# Como fazer download automático em site que chama JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, download, webclient

Preciso fazer um  programa que faça download de PDFs de diversos sites diariamente e automaticamente. É muito fácil realizar essa operação usando o comando WebClient do C#, no entanto, em certos sites não é possivel achar a URL de download de jeito algum. No evento do `click` do botão de download, o código do site chama um JavaScript e em nenhum momento é gerado um link, já tentei fazer uma `webrequest` contendo os cookies da sessão na tentativa de conseguir baixar o PDF pela resposta do servidor (usei o fiddler para identificar), mas não obtive sucesso.

Clique em "pesquisar diarios" no [canto esquerdo do site](http://aplicacao2.jt.jus.br/dejt/f/n/diariocon).

Usando a DLL Watin, que é um simulador de *web browser*, consigo simular o *click* do botão no navegador, mas não é possivel lidar com a janela "Deseja salvar ou abrir o arquivo" do Internet Explorer.

Existe algum método de realizar download em sites como esse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar dele está dando o submit do form por javascript em algum momento uma requisição Http é enviada com os dados de solicitação para o servidor devolver o arquivo certo, sugiro você analisar o head do http request e ver quais parâmetros ele envia no form, fiz um teste aqui e vem o Form Data com alguns parâmetros com números aleatórios, acho q você pode com base nisso ver qual é o parâmetro principal para a solicitação do pdf

Por exemplo nesse caso na linha 5287 do arquivo Common1_2_13.js, acontece o submit de um POST do form.

Esse caso é bem complicado de fazer um crawler, por quem tem muito código gerado automaticamente e o site exige uma sessão que expira em 30 minutos.

Quanto a sua alternativa de utilizar um simulado de web browser já utilizei o Selenium, se eu não me engano ele tem driver para vários navegadores ( http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: Estou usando o selenium, nesse simulador é possivel definir o download como automatico, pulando assim, a janela de download do IE. Muito obrigado pela resposta, abraço!